# Can we find linear combination with of its columns that give a vector with non negative coordinates for any $n\times n$ anti symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given A $\in M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R})$ an anti symmetric matrix $(A^T = -A)$, lets write its columns as : $C_1,...,C_n$, we want to show that there exists n non-negative numbers: $a_1 ,..., a_n$ (which are not all 0) such that $a_1C_1+...+a_nC_n$ is a vector with non-negative coordinates.

---

I first thought to define the set P as all vectors with non-negative coordinates (over real numbers) and if we can find a vector $v \in P$ with $Av$ is in P then we are done, otherwise I wanted to look over the set $M_{nxn} (\mathbb{R}) $\P and infer the existence over there- I'm not sure how to continue or if the beginning of my solution is valid

I'll accept any solution there is, thanks in advance

Comment: With "non-negative", do you mean $>0$ or $\geq 0$ ?

Comment: >0 or equal to 0 (second option)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very interesting. Skew symmetry is preserved under orthogonal similarity, but being entrywise nonnegative is a basis dependent property. I have yet to understand how to reconcile these two seemingly conflicting properties.

Anyway, you are essentially asking that when $A$ is real skew symmetric, whether there exists a nonnegative and nonzero vector $x$ such that $Ax\ge0$. I'm not sure if there is a simpler and more direct proof, but a stronger result by Tucker (1956) states that there actually exists some $x\ge0$ such that $Ax\ge0$ **and** $Ax+x>0$.

See, e.g. [Tucker's theorem from Farkas lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1203122) on this site, or lemma 3 (Tucker existence lemma) on p.15 of Giorgio Giorgi (2014), [*Again on the Farkas Theorem and the Tucker Key Theorem Proved Easily*](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Again-on-the-Farkas-Theorem-and-the-Tucker-Key-Giorgi/2d802c64e5ecb6f08244b9fd4fce0d6337fdec45).